# Laravel 9.x and MySQL how to issue an Update on millions of records

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a project where certain records in a table will "expire" after so many days.
I use soft deletes so basically all I have to do is set the deleted_at column.
Currently the generated SQL is as below:

```
    update st_photos set deleted_at = '2022-05-03 05:00:01', updated_at = '2022-05-03 05:00:01' 
    where user_id in (select id from users where account_code = 'S') and created_at < '2022-03-04 05:00:01' and in_storage = 0 and deleted_at is null
```

Right now there are only about 16 million records and the update statement is taking about 65 seconds to finish.
What happens is if other code tries to insert a record into that table when the above update first starts then the insert fails with a Lock Wait Timeout.

Is there a way to somehow break the update statement into smaller batches to give other sql commands time to run? My biggest concern is NOT how long the process of the update takes, I just don't want any given batch update to run for longer than about 30 seconds so it does not lock other sql commands out for too long.

One way I could do it is group the users in the subselect so that it processes the photos in batches, but I was wondering if anyone else has a better, easier to implement method of doing it.

if it helps below is the laravel code snippets that generate the above SQL.

```
self::getExpiredMediaQuery(AppConstants::ACCOUNT_CODE_STANDARD)->update(['deleted_at' => $now, 'updated_at' => $now]);
...
    public static function getExpiredMediaQuery($accountCode) {
        $dateExpired = Carbon::now()->subDays(AppConstants::$accountProperties[$accountCode]['mediaRetentionDays']);

        $query = Photo::whereIn('user_id', function ($query) use ($accountCode) {
            $query->select('id')->from('users')
                ->where('account_code', $accountCode);
            })
            ->where('created_at', '<', $dateExpired)
            ->where('in_storage', false);
        return $query;
    }
```

Comment: I understand you're looking at batching rather than general performance, but for reference: `WHERE <field> IN ()` [is notoriously slow](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=568&m=0). I realise that's the SQL generated by Laravel and you can't control it much, but you'd probably find significant performance improvements by manually writing the query with `DB()` and using a JOIN (or trying to tune the Eloquent to do that).

Answer (score 1):

Use some [chunking](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#chunking-results) method like `chunkById()`. Something like this should work to break up the job into manageable pieces.

```php
self::getExpiredMediaQuery(AppConstants::ACCOUNT_CODE_STANDARD)
    ->chunkById(
        1000,
        fn(Photo $p) => $p->update(['deleted_at' => $now, 'updated_at' => $now])
    );
```

---

I'd be interested in seeing an up-to-date reference for the suggestion in comments that `WHERE … IN` is slow, but as mentioned the query in the method could be generated with a join, though using query builder is preferable to dumping a raw query into a call to `DB`:

```php
Photo::join("users", "photos.user_id", "=", "users.id")
    ->where("photos.in_storage", false)
    ->where("photos.created_at", "<", $date_expired)
    ->where("users.account_code", $accountCode)
    // the joined values are not Eloquent models
    // if there are soft deletes they have to be filtered manually
    ->whereNull("users.deleted_at");
```

The same chunking approach as above could then be used.

Comment: would your example actually have to retrieve all the records from the database to the calling server? If so is there a way instead to have an update statement return the last primary key updated rather than record count so I could somehow process 1000 records at a time at the MySQL server and not have to retrieve the record data to the calling/php server?

Comment: No, IIRC it builds the same query but with `WHERE id > $last_id ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000` where `$last_id` is the max ID of the last chunk it pulled.

Comment: See https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.php#L114

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel Job Batching for this kind of tasks which will be more easy way to handle in future if you had more records & more complex operation

[look after this laravel docs for more](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: All of this code is already running in a background queue, well technically it is a background cron job which is scheduled to run daily at a certain time. The problem is if the query is resulting in a single long running operation on the database then a lock is made on that table until the operation finishes. So other code running on other servers that are trying to insert a record into that table are being locked out and eventually they timeout after 50 seconds. which is why I need to break this operation into smaller/faster operations giving time between for other DB operations.